# What animals are all these Sonic characters?

Tags: character-identification, sonic-the-hedgehog

[image: Image of Sonic characters]

Sonic is a Hedgehog. His full name confirms it and he also looks like real hedgehog; only his spikes/quills are blue.

[image: Image of Hedgehog]

Shadow and Silver also look like hedgehog because of their nose and spikes/quills. I am tempted to believe that Amy is also a hedgehog because she has a crush on Sonic, but she doesn't have spikes/quills (maybe, cross-species crushes are possible in their universe).

Metal Sonic is a robot. Eggman is a human. Vector is either alligator or crocodile. The one to the left of metal sonic looks like a wasp. I have no idea about Tails (I have never heard of an animal which has two tails).

What animals are all these characters?

Comment: I don't think this is too broad - we've had numerous other "who/what are all these sci-fi things?" questions and none of them were closed. My issue with this question is that you quite clearly have not done any prior research. Typing "sonic tails" into Google gives you multiple results on the first page telling you Tails' species, *and* an infobox at the bottom that lists every character in that image and more.

Answer (score 2):

From the top you have:

> Modern Sonic, Classic Sonic, Modern Tails, Classic Tails, Knuckles, Amy
>
> Cream, Blaze, Rouge, Shadow, Silver, Espio
>
> Vector, Charmy, Metal Sonic, Modern Eggman, Classic Eggman

Both Sonics, Amy, Shadow and Silver
are hedgehogs.

Both Tails are two-tailed fox (multiple tailed foxes are common in Japanese culture).

Knuckles is an echidna

Cream is a rabbit

Blaze is a cat

Rouge is a bat

Espio is a chameleon

Charmy is a bee

Vector is a crocodile

Metal sonic is a robot

Both Eggmans/robotnics are humans

Comment: You might want to know that multiple-tailed Japanese foxes are called [kitsunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune) :)

Comment: What about Silver and that blue thing floating over Cream?

Comment: Silver is a hedgehog and the blue thing is a Chao called Cheese. I encountered most of them in Sonic Heroes where you have teams of three with different abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Both Sonics, Silver, Shadow, and Amy Rose are all hedgehogs.
Both tails' are foxes.
Knuckles is an echidna.
Cream is a rabbit.
Cheese is a chao.
Blaze is cat.
Rouge is a bat.
Espio is a chameleon.
Vector is a crocodile.
Charmy is a bee.
Metal sonic is a robot.
Both Eggheads are humans.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this you could [edit] in to back it up?